# Where is t=0 in the domain?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given: $f(t,u(t)) = u'(t)=t\cdot \text{exp}(u(t))$ and $u(t_0)=u_0$

We have as solution $u(t)=-\ln(e^{-u_0}+\frac{1}{2} t_0²-\frac{1}{2}t²)$ as here: [Wolfram's solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve[%7Bu%27[t]%3D%3Dt+Exp[u[t]]%2Cu[t0]%3D%3Du0%7D%2Cu[t]%2Ct])

It somehow bothers me that whatever $t_0$ is chosen, it is between the two asymptotes $\pm \sqrt{t_0²+2e^{-u_0}}$. It would mean that the only solution for every $(t_0,u_0)$ is our $u(t)$ and that it would only exist for every $ t \in [t_0,\sqrt{t_0²+2e^{-u_0}})$ and for every $t \in (-\sqrt{t_0²+2e^{-u_0}},t_0]$

And it would also mean that you can't have $u(t)=-\ln(\frac{1}{2}t²-e^{u_0}-\frac{1}{2} t_0²)$ for every $t \in (-\infty,-\sqrt{t_0²+2e^{-u_0}})$ or for every $t \in (\sqrt{t_0²+2e^{-u_0}},\infty)$ because again, $t_0$ is between the asymptotes.

Is the reasoning in the first paragraph correct? And is there an other reason /perspective why we can't have the solution $u(t)$ as described in the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct: whatever initial condition you choose, eventually, your solution will 'blow up' (this is the appropriate technical term, believe it or not). The reason for this is that the right hand side of the ODE 'grows too fast' due to the term $e^u$ present. This is actually a classical example of an ODE which exhibits finite time blow-up.

I think the best thing to do is to refer to [this question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36970/criterion-for-finite-time-blowup-of-an-ode) on criteria for finite time blow-up. Note that a sufficient condition for global existence (i.e. for all time) is Lipschitz continuity of the right hand side of the ODE on the entire domain, see for example [these course notes](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~jswlamb/DynamIC/M2AA1-2010/M2AA1notes10Ch4.pdf) by Jeroen Lamb.